# How do I take data from a deeply nested structure based on a value inside of what I want?

Tags: xml, perl

I have this datastructure:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'cdr' => [
                   {
                     'networkInfo' => {
                                      'extPayer' => '50351851444',
                                      'eventSource' => 'J@nus',
                                      'sequenceNumber' => '0',
                                      'connectionId' => '0050351851444',
                                      'payer' => '50351851444',
                                      'status' => '1',
                                      'mvnoId' => '2',
                                      'currentStatus' => '2',
                                      'eventReferenceNumber' => '1510141545000003101',
                                      'sessionId' => '1510143920000000011',
                                      'errorCode' => '0',
                                      'previousStatus' => '1',
                                      'eventDateTime' => '20151014154533',
                                      'requestType' => '51',
                                      'actionDateTime' => '20151014154533',
                                      'exponent' => '-6'
                                    },
                     'payerInfo' => {
                                    'newPayerStatus' => '2',
                                    'noOfPayerValidity' => '0',
                                    'prevPayerStatus' => '1',
                                    'noOfWalletsUsed' => '0',
                                    'baseWalletBalance' => '0'
                                  },
                     'pricedInfo' => {
                                     'totalUsedUnits' => '0',
                                     'taxingOptionUsed' => '0',
                                     'totalSalePrice' => '0',
                                     'totalTax' => '0',
                                     'totalCostPrice' => '0',
                                     'chargeSummary' => {
                                                        'dimensionSummary' => {
                                                                              'dimensionId' => '0',
                                                                              'componentSummary' => {
                                                                                                    'totalSalePrice' => '0',
                                                                                                    'totalCostPrice' => '0',
                                                                                                    'componentId' => '0',
                                                                                                    'totalDiscountAmount' => '0',
                                                                                                    'bucketsUsed' => '0'
                                                                                                  }
                                                                            }
                                                      },
                                     'totalDiscountAmount' => '0',
                                     'bucketsUsed' => '0'
                                   }
                   },
                   {
                     'networkInfo' => {
                                      'extPayer' => '50351851444',
                                      'eventSource' => 'J@nus',
                                      'sequenceNumber' => '0',
                                      'connectionId' => '0050351851444',
                                      'payer' => '50351851444',
                                      'status' => '1',
                                      'mvnoId' => '2',
                                      'currentStatus' => '2',
                                      'eventReferenceNumber' => '1510141545000003101',
                                      'sessionId' => '1510143920000000021',
                                      'errorCode' => '0',
                                      'previousStatus' => '2',
                                      'eventDateTime' => '20151014154535',
                                      'requestType' => '53',
                                      'actionDateTime' => '20151014154535',
                                      'exponent' => '-6'
                                    },
                     'payerInfo' => {
                                    'newPayerStatus' => '2',
                                    'noOfPayerValidity' => '0',
                                    'prevPayerStatus' => '2',
                                    'noOfWalletsUsed' => '0',
                                    'baseWalletBalance' => '0'
                                  },
                     'pricedInfo' => {
                                     'totalUsedUnits' => '0',
                                     'taxingOptionUsed' => '0',
                                     'totalSalePrice' => '0',
                                     'totalTax' => '0',
                                     'totalCostPrice' => '0',
                                     'chargeSummary' => {
                                                        'dimensionSummary' => {
                                                                              'dimensionId' => '0',
                                                                              'componentSummary' => {
                                                                                                    'totalSalePrice' => '0',
                                                                                                    'totalCostPrice' => '0',
                                                                                                    'componentId' => '0',
                                                                                                    'totalDiscountAmount' => '0',
                                                                                                    'bucketsUsed' => '0'
                                                                                                  }
                                                                            }
                                                      },
                                     'totalDiscountAmount' => '0',
                                     'bucketsUsed' => '0'
                                   }
                   },
                   {
                     'networkInfo' => {
                                      'extPayer' => '50351851444',
                                      'eventSource' => 'J@nus',
                                      'sequenceNumber' => '0',
                                      'connectionId' => '0',
                                      'payer' => '50351851444',
                                      'status' => '1',
                                      'mvnoId' => '2',
                                      'currentStatus' => '2',
                                      'eventReferenceNumber' => '0',
                                      'sessionId' => '2015101400000335940',
                                      'errorCode' => '0',
                                      'previousStatus' => '2',
                                      'eventDateTime' => '20151014154540',
                                      'requestType' => '3',
                                      'actionDateTime' => '20151014154535',
                                      'exponent' => '-6',
                                      'forceDebit' => '0'
                                    },
                     'payerInfo' => {
                                    'newPayerStatus' => '2',
                                    'noOfPayerValidity' => '0',
                                    'prevPayerStatus' => '2',
                                    'noOfWalletsUsed' => '0',
                                    'baseWalletBalance' => '9998000000'
                                  },
                     'pricedInfo' => {
                                     'totalUsedUnits' => '0',
                                     'taxingOptionUsed' => '0',
                                     'totalSalePrice' => '0',
                                     'totalTax' => '0',
                                     'totalCostPrice' => '0',
                                     'chargeSummary' => {
                                                        'dimensionSummary' => {
                                                                              'dimensionId' => '0',
                                                                              'componentSummary' => {
                                                                                                    'totalSalePrice' => '0',
                                                                                                    'totalCostPrice' => '0',
                                                                                                    'componentId' => '0',
                                                                                                    'totalDiscountAmount' => '0',
                                                                                                    'bucketsUsed' => '0'
                                                                                                  }
                                                                            }
                                                      },
                                     'totalDiscountAmount' => '0',
                                     'bucketsUsed' => '0'
                                   }
                   },
                   {
                     'networkInfo' => {
                                      'extPayer' => '50351851444',
                                      'instanceId' => '0',
                                      'imei' => '0',
                                      'passwordId' => '0',
                                      'networkUsageIdentifier' => '67060224951',
                                      'ReleaseCause' => '01144',
                                      'spendControlId' => '0',
                                      'defaultPayer' => '50351851444',
                                      'sessionId' => '1510141545000003101',
                                      'chargingGroupNumberDiscountPercent' => '0',
                                      'errorCode' => '0',
                                      'calledPartyAddress' => '0050399051801',
                                      'callingPartyAddress' => '0050351851444',
                                      'semiAutoCollectClassId' => '0',
                                      'destinationZoneCode' => '1021',
                                      'requestType' => '1001',
                                      'redirectingPartyId' => '',
                                      'ApplicationServer' => '7060261771',
                                      'chargingGroupDiscountPercent' => '0',
                                      'timeZone' => '+1Q',
                                      'chargingGroupClass' => '0',
                                      'ccRequestType' => '3',
                                      'defaultExtPayer' => '50351851444',
                                      'carrierCode' => '',
                                      'PrefixDialled' => '',
                                      'dialingType' => '99',
                                      'connectionType' => '0',
                                      'mcc' => '706',
                                      'locationInfo' => '2495100001',
                                      'originalCalledPartyId' => '',
                                      'specialNumberClassId' => '0',
                                      'eventDateTime' => '20151014154535',
                                      'bearerService' => '0',
                                      'smscRefernceNumber' => '',
                                      'sequenceNumber' => '0',
                                      'redirectionInformation' => '',
                                      'unitType' => '0',
                                      'connectTime' => '20151014154535',
                                      'holidayCode' => '0',
                                      'imsi' => '51851444',
                                      'serviceIdentifier' => '0',
                                      'ratingZoneType' => '1',
                                      'mscAddress' => '',
                                      'enterpriseCall' => '0',
                                      'isTollFree' => '0',
                                      'specialLocationClassId' => '0',
                                      'routingNumber' => '',
                                      'eventType' => '0',
                                      'payerType' => '0',
                                      'connectionId' => '0050351851444',
                                      'payer' => '50351851444',
                                      'subscriberClass' => '0',
                                      'chargingGroupId' => '0',
                                      'callReferenceNumber' => '3031303032303031',
                                      'mvnoId' => '2',
                                      'originatingNetworkId' => '1021',
                                      'callType' => '1',
                                      'dialDigitId' => '1041',
                                      'actionDateTime' => '20151014154535',
                                      'callTerminationCause' => '1',
                                      'vpnGroupId' => '0',
                                      'mnc' => '02',
                                      'exponent' => '-6'
                                    },
                     'payerInfo' => {
                                    'newPayerStatus' => '2',
                                    'noOfPayerValidity' => '0',
                                    'prevPayerStatus' => '2',
                                    'walletDetails' => {
                                                       'walletId' => '1',
                                                       'prevWalletBalance' => '10000000000',
                                                       'prevExpiryDate' => '20991231',
                                                       'expiryFlag' => '0',
                                                       'newWalletBalance' => '9998000000',
                                                       'newExpiryDate' => '20991231'
                                                     },
                                    'noOfWalletsUsed' => '1',
                                    'baseWalletBalance' => '9998000000'
                                  },
                     'pricedInfo' => {
                                     'totalUsedUnits' => '120',
                                     'totalCostPrice' => '2000000',
                                     'bucket' => {
                                                 'rateId' => '1002',
                                                 'discountPercentage' => '0',
                                                 'startUnits' => '1',
                                                 'exchangeRate' => '1000000',
                                                 'taxFormulaId' => '1002',
                                                 'componentId' => '0',
                                                 'taxWalletId' => '1',
                                                 'currencyRateId' => '1',
                                                 'discountArticleId' => '1001',
                                                 'walletId' => '1',
                                                 'salePrice' => '2000000',
                                                 'discountAmount' => '0',
                                                 'TaxDetail' => {
                                                                'Tax' => {
                                                                         'amount' => '0',
                                                                         'count' => '1',
                                                                         'article' => '1009'
                                                                       }
                                                              },
                                                 'usedUnits' => '120',
                                                 'endUnits' => '120',
                                                 'taxApplied' => '0',
                                                 'debitedValue' => '2000000',
                                                 'costPrice' => '2000000',
                                                 'dimensionId' => '0',
                                                 'serviceKey' => '0',
                                                 'chargeArticleId' => '1',
                                                 'tariffId' => '1026'
                                               },
                                     'taxingOptionUsed' => '0',
                                     'totalTax' => '0',
                                     'totalSalePrice' => '2000000',
                                     'chargeSummary' => {
                                                        'dimensionSummary' => {
                                                                              'dimensionId' => '0',
                                                                              'componentSummary' => {
                                                                                                    'totalSalePrice' => '2000000',
                                                                                                    'totalCostPrice' => '2000000',
                                                                                                    'componentId' => '0',
                                                                                                    'totalDiscountAmount' => '0',
                                                                                                    'bucketsUsed' => '1'
                                                                                                  }
                                                                            }
                                                      },
                                     'bucketsUsed' => '1',
                                     'totalDiscountAmount' => '0'
                                   }
                   }
                 ]
        };
```

I want to retrieve `requestType` from every `networkInfo` parameter. We have 3 to 4 network info parameter, I want to retrieve only `requestType=1001`. How can I achieve this?

I am using XML::Simple and I want to stick with that only.

Comment: Can you expand on your constraints on using `XML::Simple`? Because this is actually very easy using an XPATH expression. (which `XML::Simple` doesn't do, but less nasty XML parsers handle just fine)

Comment: Because later I am doing lot of coding based on that so I will store requestType into particular variable and I am not that good in programming please help on this

Comment: In which case - seriously - chuck out `XML::Simple` and use something else. `XML::Twig` makes this easy.

Comment: If you only want the `requestType` of every `networkInfo` where the `requestType` is `1001`, does that mean you want to count how many `requestType` of value `1001` there are?

Answer (score 4):

Look, seriously. The reason `XML::Simple` says:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged.

Is because this sort of task is actually shockingly easy using an `xpath` expression.

Guessing slightly at your source XML (give me some sample XML, and I can give you a more precise answer), if `requestType` is an attribute this would be:

```
use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ('your_stuff.xml'); 
my $netinf = $twig -> get_xpath('//networkInfo[@requestType="1001"]',0);
```

Or if it's a node and you want all of them:

```
foreach my $requestType ( $twig -> get_xpath('//networkInfo/requestType') ) {
    print $requestType -> text;
}
```

With that data structure above, we aren't talking about an XML problem, we're talking about a data structure traversal problem. And your data structure is big and complicated.

If you want to go down that road, then the trick is - count the brackets in `Data::Dumper`, because they tell you when you're getting a hash(ref) or an array(ref).

You can get what you want with:

```
foreach my $hashref (  @{$VAR1->{cdr}} ) {
   print $hashref->{networkInfo}->{requestType},"\n";
}
```

But that is going to be a nuisance to maintain and work with, so for the sake of your future maintenance programmers - don't use `XML::Simple`.

Comment: it is throwing this below                                                                   errorCan't use string ("XML::Twig") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm

Comment: That's an entirely different question, and one I can't answer without some example code. But I'll point out - 5.8.8 is a really old version of perl too. As a beginning programmer, you don't do yourself any favours by using an en of life interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need count of elements?

```
my @elems = grep { 1001 == $_ }
            map { $_->{networkInfo}->{requestType} }
            @{ $VAR1->{cdr} };
my $count = scalar @elems;
```